# CP_SAT: Is it possible to limit the RAM used?

Tags: or-tools

Do you know if in python there is a parameter to limit the RAM used by CP_SAT to a certain value?

Answer (score 2):

There is a parameter,  but it is only checked in the pure sat solver.

You can do it externally. The time limit in C++ or the callbacks in non C++ languages have an atomic boolean that indicates if search should be stopped.

You can fire a thread that will check the process memory every second, and stop the search if it exceed a given threshold.

See this [part of the doc](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/solver.md#stopping-search-early).

Comment: Thanks Laurent, from your answer I see that there is a way to stop the search if a threshold is reached, while I'm looking for a way to just limit the amount of memory used because I see that, with my scenario to solve, 8 workers on a laptop with 4GB takes all of them, while on a server with 32GB the same workers (with the same scenario to solve) takes 15GB...it seems to me that they get the best they need

Comment: There are no mechanism to limit the mem used, the solver needs it. You need to decompose your problem and solve it in smaller chunks.